# Silicon Power SSD ATA password protected disk wipe

Tags: passwords, hdparm

I have bought Silicon Power SSD S55 disk on eBay. Unfortunately it turned out to be with ATA password protection. Can I wipe or reset it to use as new drive?

I have found instructions how to `secure erase` with `hdparm` utility, but I can't find the master password for SP manufacturer and there is no any PSID on the disk case.

Comment: Simply start a claim against seller.

Comment: It's already long time passed since I bought the disk. My mistake that I didn't check it on time :(

Comment: On serverfault.com, questions related to home and end users are off-topic. What is the timeframe for this rule? Is it a month, a year, or a century?